# REST API update a PIN (PUT vs PATCH vs POST)

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, spring-boot, security, api-design

I am creating a simple [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) RESTful API with spring boot for managing 4 digit [PINs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number).
I am having problems on which HTTP verbs to use.

Here are my assumptions:

- For create, the most adequate verbs should be `POST` or `PUT`. I'm using `PUT` because it's idempotent (it will affect the resource only once, independently of how many requests are sent)
- for partial updates I'm using `PATCH`
- for full updates I'm using `PUT`

The thing is, I'm concerned about security issues. This service will run inside a container in a AWS private cloud and accessed by other services in the same cloud.

[This infosec answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63604/put-vs-post-for-password-update) says that for updates `POST` is more correct (than `PUT`), but from a security point of view it doesn't matter because the call will be called in https.

On the other hand, [this page](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/) says that `POST` should be used in order to "hide" the PIN from the query request.

So, my question is: which HTTP verb**s** should I use? Answers from experts on API design are greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This is a spring-boot microservice (MS) in ECS. Will be consumed from other internal MSs. Purpose is to manage and validate user's PINs.

**Model:**

- This is a user's pin with a propertyX associated. The property is in a enum.
- userId is a id from other table used in several Mss/DBs and has no constraints (no FK, etc).
- DB: Aurora with only 1 table: id (auto-increment), userId, pin(code), propertyX

**Desired endpoints/operations:**

- create PIN entity. (input: userId, pinCode, property)
- validate pinCode. (input: userId + pin)
- update just pinCode. (input: userId, newPinCode)
- delete PIN entity. (input: userId)
- get propertyX. (input: userId)
- update just propertyX. (input: userId newPropertyX)

Comment: If you want architecture guidance then you'll need to provide more information on what your API looks like, such as what resource you are creating with the POST or PUT, the URL scheme, is a PIN a subresource for a user, and so on? A more straight-forward question might be to ask about the security differences between PUT and POST. The question is a little broad right now.

Comment: @bwest question updated

Comment: If you care about the security, then you should send encoded PIN instead to the API. I don't think the POST/PUT matters here.

Comment: @LunaticJape can you explain how that is possible? How to encode the PIN before passing it in the request, being the HTTP method the first point of contact with the API?